# Making the JSON deserialization work in case of Generics?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following:

```
public class BaseEntity<T> where T: class
{
    public OperationStatus OperationStatus { set; get; }
    public List<T> List { set; get; }

    protected internal BaseEntity()
    {
        if (OperationStatus == null)
        {
            OperationStatus = new OperationStatus();
            OperationStatus.IsSuccess = true;
        }

        this.List = new List<T>();
    }

    internal BaseEntity(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        if (OperationStatus == null)
        {
            OperationStatus = new OperationStatus();
            OperationStatus.IsSuccess = true;
        }

        this.List = new List<T>();
        foreach (T k in list)
        {
            this.List.Add(k);
        }
    }

}

public class KeyValuePair
{
    public string key;
    public string value;
}

public class KeyValuePairList : BaseEntity<KeyValuePair>
{
    public KeyValuePairList() { }
    public KeyValuePairList(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair> list)
        : base(list) { }
}

// Multiple other classes like KeyValuePair but all have the
// same behavior so they have been derived from BaseEntity
```

Now in my code, I am trying to map a JSON string to an instance of `KeyValuePair` list and I'm currently doing it as follows:

```
result = 
@"{
    \"d\": {
        \"OperationStatus\": {
            \"IsSuccess\": true,
            \"ErrorMessage\": null,
            \"ErrorCode\": null,
            \"InnerException\": null
        },
        \"List\": [{
            \"key\": \"Key1\",
            "\value\": \"Value1\"
        }, {
            \"key\": \"Key2\",
            \"value\": \"Value2\"
        }]
    }
}"
```

**Attempt #1**

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
KeyValuePairList output = serializer.Deserialize<KeyValuePairList>(result);
```

However, this does not work because the constructor of `KeyValuePairList` is not being called with any arguments. If I remove that constructor, JSON serialization fails with an error `No parameterless constructor found`. How can I tell `KeyValuePairList` to use `KeyValuePair` as the template in its invocation? Or maybe how can I adapt JSON serializer for this purpose?

**Attempt #2**

I tried `JSON.net` too, as follows:

```
var oo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyValuePairList>(result);
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the solution is simpler than I thought it would be. The problem is that the server is returning the JSON string with the root node `d`. Because of this the deserializing fails because it doesn't know what to do with the root node `d`. This can be solved as follow:

**Step 1:** Add an additional class JSONWrapper that wraps incoming JSON strings:

```
public class JSONWrapper<T> where T:class
{
    public T d {set; get;}
}
```

**Step 2:** Deserialize using this new class instead

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var oo = serializer.Deserialize<JsonWrapper<KeyValuePairList>>(result);
```

Much more in-line with my whole logic so I don't have to make any major changes. Thanks to everyone else who helped me out with their valuable time.

Comment: OK, your question, your solution. But it is too much code for me just to deserialize a simple json.

Answer (score 0):

Try `T[]` instead of `List<T>`

You should have two properties as,

```
public T[] Items{
    get{
        return ItemList.ToArray();
    }
    set{
        ItemList.Clear();
        ItemList.AddRange(value);
    }
}

[ScriptIgnore]
public List<T> ItemList {get;set;}
```

Items as array will be serialized in JSON and you can use ItemList for your other operations.

Comment: Thank you. Some more clarity would be great. Because I was using `List` before, I could just use the `Add` method of the list. This modification will break the existing code (the part inside the constructor where I add elements to the list). Any workaround for that?